# Redirect to community page from email

Tags: apex, community

I have a page in my community that shows all cases for the currently signed-in user. I want to redirect my users to this page via a button rendered in an email message sent to them.

I've been able to modify the url in my Visualforce email template so that it sends users to the page mentioned above. When users land on this page, they are not able to see their cases. If I change the url so they land in the community home page and then they go to the Cases tab, they are able to see their cases.

How can I redirect my users to my case page where they can see their cases?

Comment: did you validate both url and see if there is any missing parameter?